# Excel Column Equal to Text and Cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I'm trying to fill a column with an url as the text and column data directly after the slash in the url from another column.

For example i want to input http://xxx.xxx.xxx/ column data goes here

The text would be the url address and right after the slash is where i need the column data to go.

can anyone help me out?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `CONCATENATE` function.

`=CONCATENATE("http://xxx.xxx.xxx/", A1)`

Comment: Instead of `CONCATENATE` you may use `&` with the same effect: try `="http://xxx.xxx.xxx/"&A1` and see the result is identical.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to use a formula like this:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(A2,B2))
```

... in which case you'd get the following results (given that the links etc. are on row 2 of the spreadsheet):

```
A                       B   C
http://www.example.com/ xyz http://www.example.com/xyz
```

With the formula above in cell C2, not only do you have the concatenated link, but the user can click on it to open a browser at the linked page.